# Should I care about storage quotas when developer hosted add-in?

Tags: office-365, storage

I am developing SharePoint add-in, and I am wondering if requests in the add-in would have an effect on storage quotas in SharePoint? or is it just limited to sandbox solutions? I can't understand these things about storage quotas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource quotas are for sandbox solutions only.